# Full-screen CSS frame for all resolutions, no matter the content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something. Lets take for example I have a div inside the body, or body itself, and I give it a border with some margin and I give it a 100% width and height, but since I need content for it to stretch downwards..

So I have something like this:

[image: Div with full with and small height]

And this is how I want it to be on every resolution, no matter of the content in it:

[image: Fullscreen div]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have 100% width and height set on the body?  HTML I believe needs 100% height too.

Comment: To clarify: you want the div to be the exact size of the body, minus border and margin of the div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example: http://run.plnkr.co/qax6TBmBe1QeF3xg/

CSS:

```
.container
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  border:solid 2px black;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OP should use this answer, but depending on the situation - this may be helpful. Change CSS slightly: `position:fixed; overflow:auto` - http://jsfiddle.net/tQHs5/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Any problems that might occur with the content?

Comment: @user3466235: Content outside the div will be overlapped. For a fix, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24743711/1079573).

Comment: you can add overflow:auto; to make sure content would be srollable

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. If you're OK with the div being taken out of the normal document flow (meaning other elements will be overlapped by it or overlap it), then use absolute positioning ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GwCC8/1/)):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;

/* border, margin, etc. styles */
```

To allow scrolling within it, add ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GwCC8/2/)):

```
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
```

---

If you want it to be like a normal div and other content to flow around it, do the following ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M4SLA/1/)):

```
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; /* So inner elements can be relatively positioned */
    margin: 0; padding: 0; /* So scrollbars don't appear */
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;

    /* border, margin, etc. styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it. But with the help of jQuery/JS...

Just make note of below code.!

html-->markup...
css-->basic styling...
js/jquery-->"providing relative based design in the height perspective of the container/wrapper OR 'div' you are going to use.

```
<div>
  Text inside DIV...<br/>-----<br/>-----<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centur.....
</div>
```

*Please make note of below css*

```
*,*:after,*:before{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div {
  position:fixed;
  width:96%;
  top:2%;
  left:2%;
  border:20px solid #000;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

*I am using js(jquery library) for making height of container responsive.*

**Please make a note of JQUERY code,with a state & a window event.**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $("div").height(windowHeight-50);
});
$(window).resize(function(e){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $("div").height(windowHeight-50);
});
```

**NOTE**: Here I had inserted all the text into itself...!

For more futuristic, you can update css styling of `div` so that border stick to the body border.

Please make a note of below link..

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Yeswanth-JG/pen/cFiga)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution, no `position: absolute;` is required.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh8qb/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding: 10px;
}
#wrap {
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: From OP: "a border **with some margin**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: But now there's a scrollbar.